# React-router redirection 'parent' url

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

I am struggling with something which looks really simple.

So lets say I have an url like this one

http://192.168.88.226:3000/test/a/hello

and I want to redirect to http://192.168.88.226:3000/test/b/hello

right now this is my code

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
<Redirect to="b/hello" />
```

But I am getting http://192.168.88.226:3000/test/a/b/hello

I dont know how to redirect "on level up" and replace a

Thank you everybody

Comment: did any of the answers solve your issue? do you need more assistance with your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the parent component with:

```
<Redirect to="../b/hello" />
```

And you can get to subsequent parents like this:

```
<Redirect to="../../b/hello" />
```

and:

```
<Redirect to="../../../b/hello" />
```

But as you can see it gets messy if you are traversing a big tree of parent nodes.

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can do is :

```
 <Redirect to="/test/b/hello" />
```

Comment: But then I get http://192.168.88.226:3000/test/a/test/b/hello so the thing is that the stuff I putt after to= is being attached after a/ instead after test/

Comment: You will not get a relative url if your url begins with a slash.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router/lib';
<Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route path="/b/hello" component={myB_HelloComponent} />
</Router>
```

but first you need to check your **react-router**'s version